How can I reset an unresponsive Kindle paperwhite to factory settings?
After a battery discharge and recharge, my Kindle Paperwhite became completely unresponsive. I can reset it with the reset button (pressing it more than 40, and more than 60 seconds), but the screen remains unresponsive after booting.
I've read somewhere about a similar problem that this can be because the Kindle is indexing the files in the background, and suggested to wat a couple of days. So I've waited at least 3 days, but nothing changed. I note that My Kindle isn't registered (due to technical issues), and it is in flight mode (WiFi is off). USB communication is working fine. The firmware version is 5.6.1.1 (2689890035).
What can I do to revive my device?

In the meantime, I found a way to reset the factory settings (here), but unfortunately this did not fix the screen unresponsiveness. Still, it answers my original question, so I'll share this.

On your computer try creating an empty text file with the name
DO_FACTORY_RESTORE without any file type ending. With your kindle
connected to your computer, put this file onto the Kindle. Don't put
into any inner folder. Eject the kindle from the computer. Then hold
the power button long enough to shut the kindle down, then turn it
back on. This should do a full factory reset. A factory reset takes
several minutes and looks like it is quit and restarting several times
before it finishes.

